# Laravel: UpdateOrCreate on Relation?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

A user **hasOne** car.

**users**

```
id | name
1  | Bob
2  | Alice
```

**cars**

```
idMember |  color  |  energy
   1     |  blue   |    0.95
```

Inside the **User** class I have

```
public function car()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Car','idMember');
}
```

I want to call updateOrCreate on the relation Model like this:

```
$user->car()->updateOrCreate(['idMember' => $user->id], ['color' => 'red', 'energy' => '0.1']);
```

However, I get the error message

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: update `cars` set `color` = red, `energy` = 0.1,
>   `updated_at` = 2018-01-12 15:26:47 where `id` is null)

Why is he looking for

> `id` is null

?

Comment: Laravel expect each entity to have an auto-incrementing primary key with the name `id` , having a primary key is also a relational requirement (though it may be a composite key which laravel does not support). Just save your sanity and add an auto incrementing `id` column in that table so everything has a unique id. Also by convention laravel expects the foreign key to be `<singular other table>_id` i.e. in your case `idMember` should be `user_id` (but you can change that in your `hasOne` parameters)

Comment: @apokryfos oh yeah your right.. forgot about that. But I rather change the `primaryKey`of my car model since no AI key is needed in a hasOne relation.

Comment: On one to one relationships having the foreign key as the primary key as you have done is also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem without adding an unnecessary auto incrementing id to the cars model:

```
class Car extends Model
{

  protected $primaryKey   = 'idMember';
  public    $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: That is fine now, but you'll run into trouble if you're at some point going to decide that a `User` can `hasMany` `Car`s, because at that point there is nothing left in the **cars** table that is 'quaranteed' to be unique.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp well for a car a hasone makes not really sense, because people may ahve more then one.. but in my complicated real life scenario I have a hasone relation that will never be a hasmany :). But even if I would want to change it, all I would have to do would change `hasOne` to `hasMany`, add the AI and remove the two top lines from the Car model.

Answer (score 12):

To be clear, your original syntax is correct. You can use it on a relation:

```
$user->car()->updateOrCreate(['idMember' => $user->id], [
    'color' => 'red',
    'energy' => '0.1',
]);
```

This will check if there is a `car` with `idMember === $user->id`; if so, update `color` and `energy`. If not, it will create a `car` record with `idMember`, `color`, and `energy`.

I haven't tested, but based on the first parameter's array type, you should be able to pass in multiple match conditions, such as

```
['idMember' => $user->id, 'day' => 'tuesday']
```

Comment: updateOrCreate / upserts in laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#upserts) and laravel news [1](https://laravel-news.com/firstornew-firstorcreate-firstor-updateorcreate)

Answer (score 2):

Your cars model should have a primary key, commonly called "id". Create it.

Comment: Thank you! That of course one way how to solve it. But I prefere the solution witouth AI in cars table

Answer (score -3):

In your model mention the primaryKey if primarykey is not "ID"

```
protected $primaryKey = "Your Primary Key";
```

If you do not need icnrementing for your primary key

```
public    $incrementing = false;
```

Thats it ..